# SoapUI DataSource

Tags: datasource, soapui

My question is with regrad to DataSource in SoapUI. The scenario is as follows:

I am running a data driven test using xls file as data source. I am reading one record at a time. I have dynamic assertions for test cases. The challenge I am facing is when I run the script for one iteration, I see all the assertions are passing, if I open the assertion and save it again, assertions fails because its reading the data from the next row. Can you please suggest the solution for this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some code so we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Not sure if you still having this problem. Would you please add the details like what kind of assertions you are using. Is expected output not part of row data?

Answer (score 0):

Data that changes per iteration, e.g each row has a different last name, is not being dynamically changed in your assertion. Either add properties in your test case that saves the changing data and update your assertions to use this data, or wildcard data that changes per each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one more column called Result in your Excel for result.
2. Add assertion (XPath match configuration) -> Select Content->step: Datasource and then the column(Result)
3. Now every time it performs with the new record in data source, it also compares with the result column.